# Where is PHPUnit API reference?

Tags: phpunit

Is there a comprehensive reference for PHPUnit somewhere?

The narrative documentation on https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/ is somewhat helpful, but I would like to see class documentation, method API signatures, etc., similar to what's provided on php.net

Does this exist?

Closest thing I've found is https://gist.github.com/loonies/1255249

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Damien Flament** has [generated it recently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41981468/3866610) with [Sami](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Sami) and [published](https://damienflament.github.io/phpunit-api-docs/). Please use class structure on the left to navigate.

---

**Edit:**

It's also available on **[official website](https://api.phpunit.de/)**.

Comment: Yep. I generated it because I encountered the same issue: where is the API documentation ? As the source is documented (with examples), it should be published. I used Sami because I like its simple interface and its ability to generate the documentation for multiple versions. It generates links to the source code hosted on the GitHub repository also !

Comment: Maybe should I show it to the PHPUnit maintainer. The narrative documentation is good. But an official API documentation alongside will be perfect !

Comment: @DamienFlament Good job Damien :) I think this is a good idea to contact with Sebastian Bergmann

Comment: I opened [an issue](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-documentation/issues/417) on the phpunit-documentation repository. The API documentation is available at [https://api.phpunit.de/](https://api.phpunit.de/) but I can't found any link to it on the PHPUnit documentation pages.

Comment: @DamienFlament What a surprise! I have edited the answer. By the way, type `site:https://api.phpunit.de` on Google - it's not even indexed.